# Cheerio Map Strange Behaviour

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm using `map` with a list of Cheerio results to return an attribute value. What I want is a variable that contains a list of attribute values (in this case ID's), but instead I'm getting the ID's and extra data.

The following code prints a list of ID's:

```
let ids = $('[data-profileid]').map(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('data-profileid'))
})
```

Result:

```
1012938412
493240324
123948532
423948234
...
```

But, the following code returns the IDs but in a different format:

```
let ids = $('[data-profileid]').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-profileid')
})

console.log(ids)
```

Results:

```
...
'69': '234234234,
'70': '9328402397432',
'71': '1324235234',
  options:
   { withDomLvl1: true,
     normalizeWhitespace: false,
     xmlMode: false,
     decodeEntities: true },
  _root:
   { '0':
      { type: 'root',
        name: 'root',
        attribs: {},
...
```

What is all this extra data? It certainly isn't required. I'd rather just have an ordinary array.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to http://api.jquery.com/map/:

> As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's
>   very common to call .get() on the result to work with a basic array.

So it looks like this should work:

```
let ids = $('[data-profileid]').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-profileid')
}).get()
```

Comment: But why is the map function not passed the node on the parameter!!!!???

Comment: @RobertMoskal I think you're thinking of [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) which takes an array as a parameter. This is using the object's (i.e., a set matched by a jQuery selector) [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/). Check the links for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 9):

> What is all this extra data? It certainly isn't required. I'd rather just have an ordinary array.

Cheerio has a *fluent* API, meaning most of its functions return an object on which additional functions can be chained. If `map` just returned an "ordinary array" then you wouldn't be able to call additional Cheerio functions on the result. There aren't a lot of ways you can chain additional function calls onto the result of *your* `map` call, which returns an array of strings, but Cheerio's developers (taking a cue from jQuery's developers) chose to keep a consistent API rather than pepper it with special cases.

If you want an ordinary array, though, Cheerio gives you a handy [`toArray`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio#toarray) function:

```
let ids = $('[data-profileid]').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('data-profileid')
});

console.log(ids.toArray());
// => [ '1012938412', '493240324', '123948532', '423948234' ]
```